# Initialise pointer to a char pointer globally

Tags: c, embedded, string

I'm doing C programming and need help with this problem..

```
char str[] = "Hello";
char * ptr = str;
char ** ptr2 = (char**)ptr;
```

I have these three lines in a header file. The first two lines are fine but an error will occur in the third line. Explicitly the error is "initializer element is not constant".

Is there any other way of assigning the address of `ptr` to `*ptr2` globally? Or is this impossible to achieve globally?
I want this done so `ptr2` can be the common access point but what it's pointing to can be changed if necessary.

Answer (score 8):

First of all, this:

```
char ** ptr2 = (char**)ptr;
```

Doesn't assign the address of `ptr` to `ptr2`. It assigns the address of `str` (contained in `ptr`) to `ptr2` and pretends its a `char**` instead of a `char*`, with possibly disastrous results later when you try to use it. You probably meant:

```
char ** ptr2 = &ptr;
```

Since `&ptr` (the address) is indeed constant, unlike `ptr` (the value), this should compile without error. Plus, it's what you really want anyway.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you want `ptr2` to point to `ptr`. This means assigning the address of `ptr` to `ptr2`, not to `*ptr2` You have to do it like this:

```
char** ptr2 = &ptr;
```

I don't understand your goal. `ptr` can be changed as necessary too.

Please consider better names for your variables.

Comment: I think the names of the variables have been masqueraded since the original variable names are probably irrelevant.